# Why this while loop executes twice before asking for name

Tags: c++

I have a function which validates a user's first and last name.  However, the while loop executes twice, and I can't find out why.... any help

```
string getName()
{
     string name = "";
     bool stop = false;
     string::iterator it;

     while(!stop)//name validation loop
     {
           cout << "enter name: ";
           getline(cin, name);

           for(it = name.begin(); it < name.end(); it++)
           {
                if(tolower(*it) > 'z' || tolower(*it) < 'a' && tolower(*it) != ' ') 
                { 
                      cout << "Error, only letters! \n"; 
                      break;
                }
                if(it == name.end()-1) { stop = true; }
           }
           cout << "here\n";
     }
     return name;
}
```

Comment: What is the input to `getline()`?

Comment: Apart from the fact that it allows more than just a first and last name, it seems to run correctly for common sense inputs.

Comment: It will fail (and do the loop twice) if there is an empty line on the input stream. Thus suggests that the input you read before this is not extracting the trailing new line character for the stream. This suggests you are doing something line `cin >> age;` just before this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It may happen if there is still some newspace character in cin buffer. std::ws extracts white spaces like newline character, space, tabulator from stream before right text. Try that:

```
string getName()
{
     string name = "";
     bool stop = false;
     string::iterator it;

     while(!stop)//name validation loop
     {
           cout << "enter name: ";
           std::cin >> std::ws;   // <--- drop whitespaces
           getline(cin, name);

           for(it = name.begin(); it < name.end(); it++)
           {
                if(tolower(*it) > 'z' || tolower(*it) < 'a' && tolower(*it) != ' ') 
                { 
                      cout << "Error, only letters! \n"; 
                      break;
                }
                if(it == name.end()-1) { stop = true; }
           }
           cout << "here\n";
     }
     return name;
}
```

Comment: I have the same exact while loop in a different file, and works just fine... before I posted this question, I deleted the file, and created a new one, but problem persisted, why is that?

Answer (score 0):

There are a few problems with your loop and this is how I'd rewrite it, keeping it as similar to your implementation as possible:

```
string getName()
{
   bool stop;
   string name;
   string::iterator it;

   do {
      stop = true;
      cout << "enter name: ";
      getline(cin, name);

      for(it = name.begin(); it < name.end(); it++)
      {
          if( (tolower(*it) > 'z' || tolower(*it) < 'a') && tolower(*it) != ' ' )
          { 
                cout << "Error, only letters! \n"; 
                stop = false;
                break;
          }
      }
      cout << "here\n";

     } while (!stop);

   return name;
}
```

With what you had here:

`if(tolower(*it) > 'z' || tolower(*it) < 'a' && tolower(*it) != ' ')`

Due to `&&` having higher precedence, it equates to:

`if(tolower(*it) > 'z' ||`**`(`**`tolower(*it) < 'a' && tolower(*it) != ' '`**`)`**`)`

which is not what you want.

**EDIT:** since `' '` (space) is `< 'a'` your code won't actually cause problems, but I'm not sure you did it like that on purpose.

I also don't like this: `if(it == name.end()-1) { stop = true; }`, and a `do...while` loop is better suited.

**EDIT:** You might also want to add a check for empty input (all whitespace), since that would seem an invalid name.

**EDIT(again):** Loki's right, you must have junk on the input stream before calling `getName`. You can use Mścisław's solution or `cin.ignore()`.